# I am trying to make a stacked bar graph but its not looking the way I want it too

Tags: ggplot2, tidyverse, geom-bar, stacked-bar-chart

I want a clear stacked bar graph showing moderate bleaching events and severe bleaching events. I want moderate to be blue and the bar graph and severe to be red, but its giving me only black and grey and its all unorganized.

```
coral_bleaching_events %>%
  group_by(location) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = location,
             y = moderate_bleaching_events + severe_bleaching_events,
             fill = factor("moderate_bleaching_events", "severe_bleaching_events")), 
                           levels = c("moderate_bleaching_events", "severe_bleaching_events")) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           color = "black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("moderate_bleach" = "blue", "severe_bleach" = "red"),
                    name = "Bleaching Events") +
  labs(x = "Location",
       y = "Total Bleaching Events") +
  theme_few() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 9, angle = 315)) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(face = "bold"))
```

[This is the graph that it gave me and im really confused on how to correct it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoHHX.png)